# GWT dispose modal dialog by clicking outside of it

Tags: gwt, user-interface, modal-dialog

I have a HSV color selector on a dialog and I would like to provide user several ways to dispose the dialog. I have normal buttons and such but I would also like to make it disappear when user clicks outside of it.

Is there a way to do this in GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable [PopupPanel auto hide](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#setAutoHideEnabled%28boolean%29). When enabled, the popup will be automatically hidden when the user clicks outside of it.

Comment: Ah, simple! I feel bit embarrassed not seeing that myself.