# How to prevent GWT dialogbox from closing when clicking outside it

Tags: gwt

I plan to add a menu that pop ups when a user performs a certain action. This menu will include some fields that the user will fill out and then hit "Submit" which will close the dialog box and update the client based on information inputed.

However, I want the user to be able to close the dialog window by hitting cancel or submit, and not by clicking on the screen outside of the dialog box.

How can i do this? Or maybe I should just use a PopupPanel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GWT dispose modal dialog by clicking outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090270/gwt-dispose-modal-dialog-by-clicking-outside-of-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as setting the auto-hide behavior to `false`, either at [construction time](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html#DialogBox%28boolean%29) or [later](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#setAutoHideEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: ah, i can't believe i didnt see that! when i read autohide, i thought it mean that don't "show" it upon creation. thanks!